# EF Core 5 creates tables twice in migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I've created a project and a migration, but it seems like the migrations does not care about previous migrations when adding new ones, that is, the migration files just tries to create the same tables twice.

I created two migrations, `First` and `Second`. What changed was I added a string property to a `Post` entity (not shown here). What I expected was something like the following:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn(...)
```

But instead I got a `Second` migration containing everything from the `First` migration but when creating the table `Post`, it had the added column. It's almost like it did not even care there was a `First` migration thus acting like its the first migration ever.

**First**

```
public partial class First : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });
    ...
```

**Second**

```
public partial class Second : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoles",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            });
    ...
```

As you can see they are identical, why is this happening?

Comment: Well - did you **apply** the `First` migraton to your database, before generating the second one?

Comment: @marc_s Yes I did, getting the list of migrations it shows the Second one as (pending). But why is that required? For me it would make sense that it can figure out what's changed since the last migration not what in the actual database.

Comment: @marc_s I found the problem, super strange but in hind sight it makes sense why everything was behaving so strangely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out for some reason visual studio for mac played tricks on me again. The following lines was added to my csproj file.

```
<Compile Remove="Migrations\MainDbContextModelSnapshot.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Migrations\20210102195131_Test1.Designer.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Migrations\20210102195131_Test1.cs" />
```

Now it all makes sense why it tried to create everything from scratch again because there was no snapshot. Anyway, if this strange thing happens to anyone else you might want to have a look in your csproj files for this. I can't explain why these are added.

The solution is simply to remove such lines if you see them and everything should work as expected.

Comment: This helped me, thanks. have been DROPing and CREATing tables because of this problem.

I think it is not because Visual Studio for Mac but since I have Excluded the folder Migration, thinking it will delete while it excludes whole folder when it compiles.

I removed those lines and now the migration did work as it should.